# Drawer blur background Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

```
drawer: Drawer(
    child: BackdropFilter(
        filter: ImageFilter.blur(sigmaX: dynamic, sigmaY: dynamic),
        child: Container()),
  ),
```

Is there some way to change sigmaX and sigmaY dynamically when drawer is drawn?

[image]

Comment: Can you provide a GIF what exactly are you trying to get?

Comment: @YeasinSheikh When you open it, so that the background is blurred like on an iPhone. I added a GIF

Answer (score 0):

I tried using Stack -> [BackDropFilter -> SizedBox.expand(), Drawer] which actually worked wonders as I didn't want to change any source files in the drawer component.
So my code now looks something like this :
Scaffold(
resizeToAvoidBottomInset: true,
drawer: SafeArea(
child: Stack(
children: [
BackdropFilter(
filter: ImageFilter.blur( sigmaX: 5.0, sigmaY: 5.0, ),
child: const SizedBox.expand(),
),
Drawer( child: ...

The backdrop is still tappable and it works just like how the accepted answer seems to work.
I tried using Stack -> [BackDropFilter -> SizedBox.expand(), Drawer] which actually worked wonders as I didn't want to change any source files in the drawer component.
So my code now looks something like this :

```
Scaffold(
       resizeToAvoidBottomInset: true,
       drawer: SafeArea(
               child: Stack(
                        children: [
                              BackdropFilter(
                                       filter: ImageFilter.blur( sigmaX: 5.0, sigmaY: 5.0, ),
                                       child: const SizedBox.expand(),
                                ),
                          Drawer( child: ...
```

The backdrop is still tappable and it works just like how the accepted answer seems to work.

Comment: This is not what I need. I want to make dynamic blurring so that the more you open the Drawer, the stronger the blur becomes.

Comment: @Samoilov  I think you need to create a custom drawer and use gesture detection which fulfils your requirement